# Kdecache-user taking up lots of space

Tags: kubuntu, kde, cache, cleanup

My computer has started to show signs of a bloated root partition.  I checked it out using `ncdu` and discovered that the directory at `/var/tmp/kdecache-user/` has swelled to 1.6 gigs.  After doing a `ls -l`, some of this stuff hasn't been touched in many months.  Question: what should I do about this behemoth?  I figure I can just clear it out but why is stuff allowed to accumulate in here?  Are there settings that govern this?  Are there best practices for cleaning it out? (Apart from not running kde)

Comment: It is a cache - you could clean (remove) it. The KDE will build the cache again when needed. Older topic from the Kubuntu Forums:  https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?57289-Anybody-has-a-giant-var-tmp-kdecache-(user-name)